# How can I check if an instance of a class exists in a List in Python 3 according to value semantics instead of object identity?

Tags: python, list, class

In Python 3, I have a list (`my_array`) that contains an instance of the `Demo` class with a certain attribute set on that instance. In my case, the attribute is `value: int = 4`.

Given an instance of the `Demo` class, how can I determine if that instance already exists in `my_array` with the same properties. Here's a MCRE of my issue:

```py
from typing import List
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value
        
my_array: List[Demo] = [Demo(4)]

print(Demo(4) in my_array)  # prints False
```

However, `Demo(4)` clearly already exists in the list, despite that it prints `False`.

I looked through the Similar Questions, but they were unrelated.

How can I check if that already exists in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an [equality function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) to `Demo`:

```py
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Demo) and self.value == other.value
```

P.S, since Python 3.9 you don't need to import `List` and just use:

```py
my_array: list[Demo] = [Demo(4)]
```

Comment: Whether this is a _useful_ solution is another matter. In the general case, overriding the equality function just so you can do this is sometimes problematic.

Comment: @tripleee Why would this be problematic...? For context, my objective is to prevent duplicate items in my list. If you know of a different way, I'm open to it. (Yes, I realize I should be using a Set, not a List)

Comment: Operator overloading to solve a narrow problem tends to produce unpleasant surprises down the line, where you find that you wanted the default behavior after all. If your code base is small and/or the use case limited, probably not a problem.

Comment: Value-based membership check incurs quite a bit of overhead. Identity-based membership check is often preferred in the real world because of its efficiency in repeated queries. Try keeping track of instances in a dict instead so membership check can be normalized to cached instances first for efficient identity-based lookups.

Comment: @tripleee for sure, got enough C++ behind me to be hit by such unpleasant surprises more than once. In Python maybe it's best to use `dataclass` or `namedtuple` when possible to get some of it out-of-the-box

Answer (score 0):

By default, for custom classes, Python compares objects by their memory addresses, not by their attribute values. In other words, two instances of a class with the same attribute values are considered different objects.

To make the comparison work based on the attribute values, you'll need to override the **eq** method in your Demo class. The **eq** method allows you to define how instances of your class should be compared for equality.

Here's an example of how you can modify your *Demo* class:

```
from typing import List

class Demo:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Demo):
            return self.value == other.value
        return False
        
my_array: List[Demo] = [Demo(4)]

print(Demo(4) in my_array)  # prints True
```

With this modification, the comparison *Demo(4)* in *my_array* will return **True** as expected.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score 0):

If you want [value semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics), you either need to implement it yourself by overriding `__eq__` to do manual comparison of each data member (and also first check for `None`, compatible class type, etc.), or, if the data members of your class also/already follow value semantics, and you don't have a reason to not want to make your class a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), just make it a dataclass.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in

> [...] For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`. [...]

[The `==` operator maps to the `eq` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions), which you override for a class in its `__eq__` magic method.

As for the dataclass suggestion the related docs are at https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-contents.

> eq: If true (the default), an [`__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method will be generated. This method compares the class as if it were a tuple of its fields, in order. Both instances in the comparison must be of the identical type.